# nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, not supported

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, certbot, ocsp

It's my first time to use certbot in docker with nginx

> - nginx version: 1.23.1
> - nginx build : docker (macbre/nginx-http3)
> - OpenSSL 1.1.1 (compatible; BoringSSL) (running with BoringSSL)

nginx throw this error when tring to use ocsp stabling

```
nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, not supported
```

cert seems to support ocsp

```bash
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -ocsp_uri
# http://r3.o.lencr.org
```

nginx ssl conf

```
# =============================================================================
# default Certificates
ssl_certificate     /certs/dir/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /certs/dir/key.pem;
# =============================================================================
ssl_dhparam         /certs/dir/dhparam.pem;

# =============================================================================
# # OCSP staplingenter code here
ssl_stapling            on;
ssl_stapling_verify     on;

# # verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
ssl_trusted_certificate /certs/dir/chain.pem;

# # replace with the IP address of your resolver
resolver            1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=1200s;
resolver_timeout    3s;

# =============================================================================
# TLS
ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

# =============================================================================
# 0-RTT QUIC connection resumption
ssl_early_data  on;

# =============================================================================
# https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=nginx&version=1.17.9&config=intermediate&openssl=1.1.1d&guideline=5.4
# Optimize session cache
# ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_timeout 4h;
# about 40000 sessions
ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;

# Enable session tickets
ssl_session_tickets off;
```

> Those didn't help:
>
> - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_stapling
> - [Nginx "ssl_stapling" ignored, host not found in OCSP responder "ocsp.comodoca.com"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405068/nginx-ssl-stapling-ignored-host-not-found-in-ocsp-responder-ocsp-comodoca-co)
> - https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ocsp.html
> - https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/installoptions
>   and more like it
> - [nginx proxy doesn't cache OCSP responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444064/nginx-proxy-doesnt-cache-ocsp-responses)
> - [Nginx OCSP_basic_verify:signer certificate not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429934/nginx-ocsp-basic-verifysigner-certificate-not-found?rq=1)
>
> and many of this list: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nginx+ocsp

---

any body has encountered this issue before ?

or could any one tell me how to overcome this ?

I want to setup ocsp with nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OpenSSL 1.1.1 (compatible; BoringSSL) (running with BoringSSL)

Based on [this discussion](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/nginx-http3-letsencrypt/181112) it looks like OCSP stapling when using BoringSSL is not fully supported. While [there is a patch](https://github.com/ononoki1/nginx-http3#features) to add support for OCSP stapling to nginx it needs to have the OCSP response provided as a file it cannot retrieve it automatically from within nginx from the OCSP responder. To cite:

> Due to usage of BoringSSL instead of OpenSSL, some directives may not work, e.g. ssl_conf_command. Besides, **direct OCSP stapling via ssl_stapling on; ssl_stapling_verify on; does not work** too. You should use ssl_stapling on; ssl_stapling_file /path/to/ocsp;. The OCSP file can be generated via ...

Comment: this command saved a lot of things `openssl ocsp -no_nonce -issuer /path/to/intermediate -cert /path/to/cert -url "$(openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert -noout -ocsp_uri)" -respout /path/to/ocsp`

Comment: is there a way to generate the file from local ca in the data center too with openssl ... for that case I have all the certs but no ocsp server ... and thanks for the answer .. it works well

Comment: @Abd-ElazizSharaf: I don't know of an easy way to create the OCSP response apart from asking the OCSP server for it - but you can run your own OCSP server and ask it. See https://bhashineen.medium.com/create-your-own-ocsp-server-ffb212df8e63

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to reconfigure certs, run my oscp server, generate ocsp file, then reconfigure my server, the trick is the first one as I see